# angular2 form validation: get an instance of ngForm

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How can I have a reference to "myform" in the component? is it possible? 
Must necessarily use a formbuilder (I'm trying to avoid using that)?

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <label class="col-sm-12" [class.ng-invalid]="!(value.valid || Value.pristine)">Value</label>
    <input type="text"  required ngControl="value" #value="ngForm" class="form-control text-center" [(ngModel)]="value" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there is another way to do this. You can use the ViewChild annotation, here your example adapted:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
<label class="col-sm-12" [class.ng-invalid]="!(value.valid || Value.pristine)">Value</label>
<input type="text"  required ngControl="value" #value="ngForm" class="form-control text-center" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

```
class MyForm {
  @ViewChild('myForm') form;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.form)
    this.form.control.valueChanges
      .subscribe(values => console.log(values));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to leverage the `FormBuilder` class and the `ngFormModel` directive instead. `ngForm` and `ngControl` are online for inline forms.

Here is a sample:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm">
  <label class="col-sm-12"
    [class.ng-invalid]="!(myForm.controls.value.valid || myForm.controls.value.pristine)">Value</label>
  <input type="text" [ngControlControl]="myForm.controls.value" 
         class="form-control text-center" [(ngModel)]="value" />
</form>
```

and in the component class:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.myForm = builder.group({
      value: ["", Validators.required],
    })
  }
}
```

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/11/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-1/